Is there a way to achieve currying with a local variable
We need to create a function that would print the results for:
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)());
So this is how I did:


let res = 0;
function sum(a){
  if(a){
    res = res + a;
    return sum; //Return the same function for next chain of actions
  }else{
    return res;
  }

}
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)());



Is there a way I can achieve this with a local res? the problem I face with making it local is, it just gets reset in the next call.
I see some solutions like this:
function sum(a) {
  return function(b){
    if(!b){
        return a;
    }
    return sum(a+b);
  }
}

But the way I did appears more natural and intuitive to me and I just want to make that work with res as local instead of gloabl.

Any reason there should even be a variable? Seems intentionally limiting but for no real reason or even gain. The traditional and most correct approaches use partial application or carry forward the state via arguments. Both answers have problems with state due to not doing that.

if (!b) is a buggy conditional, it fails expressions like sum(x)(0)(y)() because 0 is a falsey value

You can make the sum an IIFE and put res in the local scope. After that, when called with no arguments, reset the res to 0 to make it ready for the next call.


const sum = (() => {
  let res = 0;
  
  return function (a) {
    if (typeof a === 'number') {
      res = res + a;
      return sum;
    } else {
      const temp = res;
      res = 0;
      return temp;
    }
  }
})();

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)());
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)());



It can also be shortened in a simpler but maybe cursed syntax:


const sum = (res => a => {
  if (typeof a === 'number') {
    res = res + a;
    return sum;
  }
  
  try {
    return res;
  } finally {
    res = 0;
  }
})(0);

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)());
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)());




That makes sense. Thank you.

Somewhat the opposite problem of this: a = sum(1)(2); b = a(3); console.log(a(), b()); returns 6, 0

@VLAZ I'm not sure if there's a good way to solve this, besides, what would be the expected output? 3, 6?

Yes, 1+2 = 3 and 1+2+3=6, so 3, 6 is correct. And it's achievable by carrying forward the state within the chained invocations, rather than sharing it for all chains One of the simplest ways to implement it is seen here: const sum= x => y => (y !== undefined) ? sum(x + y) : x; - if an argument is provided, carry forward the sum. See demo

@VLAZ I see now, it is indeed much simpler. One tiny issue that sum must be called at least twice. I would argue that sum() should return 0, though?

Well, you can also do that. Although, given that addition is a binary operation, it's not unreasonable to expect at least two arguments. There are plenty of implementations of infinite currying, I picked one that was simple to post in a comment. You can do something like this, if you really wish: https://jsbin.com/pubuduxati/1/edit?js,console

@VLAZ missed those test cases. Thanks. That's more comprehensive.

You could do it like this:
The innerSum function maintains a closure over res. This allows res to retain its value across multiple calls to innerSum.
function sum(a) {
  let res = a;
  function innerSum(b) {
    if (b !== undefined) {
      res += b;
      return innerSum;
    } else {
      return res;
    }
  }
  innerSum.toString = function() {
    return res;
  };
  return innerSum;
}

Demo


function sum(a) {
  let res = a;
  function innerSum(b) {
    if (b !== undefined) {
      res += b;
      return innerSum;
    } else {
      return res;
    }
  }
  innerSum.toString = function() {
    return res;
  };
  return innerSum;
}

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)().toString());




Makes sense. Thank you.

@ABGR No problem, happy to help

a = sum(1)(2); b = a(3); console.log(a(), b()); returns 6, 6 which doesn't seem correct. Consider a somewhat real usage: price = sum(item1Price)(item2Price); priceWithTax = price(tax);

Consider using valueOf instead of toString since res is a number

(Updated to include a suggestion from Mulan in the comments.)
An interesting alternative is to take advantage of valueOf, toString and toJSON so that we don't have to run that final empty call:
const sum = (a) => Object.assign(
  (b) => sum(a + b), 
  {valueOf: () => a, toString: () => `${a}`, toJSON: () => a }
)

Now, for instance, sum(1)(2)(3) is a function, but because it has a valueOf method, we can use it for further calculations as if it were a number:
sum(1)(2)(3) * 10                            //=> 60

And if we use it in string-building, the toString version of its value will be used:
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3))                   //=> 6
`The total is ${sum(1)(2)(3)}`              //=> "The total is 6"

Note that sum(1)(2)(3) is an immutable wrapper around the value 6.  Adding new calls will simply return new functions that don't interfere with one another:
const firstThree = sum(1)(2)(3)

console.log(firstThree(4)(5)(6))             //=> "21"
console.log(firstThree(10))                  //=> "16" (previous 4, 5, 6 ignored)

This is useful, but is not a panacea.  There are places where the function-nature of our value could cause problems.  The first one that comes to mind is if this were to be used as a JSON value:
console.log(JSON.stringify({a: 4, b: sum(1)(2)(3), c: 10}))
//=> {a, 4, c: 10}                           // *** Note that `b` is missing ***
So you'd have to determine if you have use-cases like that.  If you don't, this is a pretty elegant version, both in usage and in implementation.
Update Mulan's suggestion of using toJSON as well as valueOf and toString means we can extract a JSON representation that includes the current value of the this function.  Of course it no longer has the dynamic behavior, but that is to be expected when it's been serialized to a string.
console.log(JSON.stringify({a: 4, b: sum(1)(2)(3), c: 10}))
//=> '{"a", 4, "b": 6, "c": 10}'             // *** Note that `b` is now fixed ***  

You can test all this in your browser in the following snippet:


const sum = (a) => Object.assign(
  (b) => sum(a + b), 
  {valueOf: () => a, toString: () => `${a}`, toJSON: () => a }
)

const res = sum(1)(2)(3) * 10               
console.log(res)                             //=> 60

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3))                    //=> 6
console.log(`The total is ${sum(1)(2)(3)}`)  //=> "The total is 6"

const firstThree = sum(1)(2)(3)

console.log(firstThree(4)(5)(6))             //=> "21"
console.log(firstThree(10))                  //=> "16" (previous 4, 5, 6 ignored)

console.log(JSON.stringify({a: 4, b: sum(1)(2)(3), c: 10}))
//=> '{"a", 4, "b": 6, "c": 10}'             // *** Note that `b` is now fixed ***
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}




to support JSON.stringify, you can add { ..., toJSON: () => a } to the object (function) assignments :D

@Mulan: quite right.  Updated.  For whatever reason, I never use toJSON, although I certainly know it exists.  This case is perfect for it!

still ruminating on valueOf.. I am realizing I do not know all of the conditions which cause the method to be called. definitely a knowledge gap for me to fill there

I've seen parts of the spec, but never investigated in detail.  But I think the general rule is  that if an object is supplied in a place where a numeric value is expected, then we'll call valueOf if it exists.

You could define sum like this -


const sum = a => b =>
  b == null ? a : sum(a + b)
  
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)()) // 10

console.log(sum(11)(11)(11)()) // 33



If you want to support sum() to return 0, another conditional is required -


const sum = a =>
  a == null
    ? 0
    : b =>
        b == null ? a : sum(a + b)

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)()) // 10

console.log(sum(11)(11)(11)()) // 33

console.log(sum()) // 0



sum is a bit inflexible and only supports addition. A better pattern permitting any function can be seen demonstrated with go below -


function go(a) {
  return function map(fn) {
    return go(fn(a))
  }
}

const add = (a) => (b) => a + b

const mul = (a) => (b) => a * b

go(2)           // 2
  (add(3))      // 5
  (add(4))      // 9
  (mul(11))     // 99
  (console.log) // => 99



Next we'll see go as a well-typed function -
interface Go<A> {
  <B>(fn: (a: A) => B): Go<B>
}

function go<A>(a: A) {
  return function map<B>(fn: (a: A) => B): Go<B> {
    return go(fn(a))
  }
}

const add = (a: number) => (b: number) =>
  a + b

const mul = (a: number) => (b: number) =>
  a * b

Try it on typescript playground
If type safety is not your concern, you can write go as simple as -
const go = x => fn => go(fn(x))


Very nice.  It very much reminds me of a demo from more than a decade ago that inspired a friend and me on our FP journey.  Of course if you define tap (= (fn) => (x) => (fn(x), x)), you can wrap it around your console.log statements and still continue the chain.

reading this thread brings me waaay back
